# Is there a method to pull string variables from a list/tuple etc to serve as variable names for other variables?

Tags: python

First, I just want to say, I know you can't assign to 'literals'.

> 1 = 15, "word" = 5

but you can input

> word = 5

if i made mylist = ["word", "black","dance", "bread"]

I fully understand that mylist[0] is a variable, I get that, but is there no fancy python method that has escaped my detection to do, for example,

```
MyList = ["word", "black","dance", "bread"]
OtherList = [ OtherClass(), 1, "Much Brave", "Such Awesome"]
for i in MyList:
    i.supersweetliteralmethodthatIvewantedsincethedaysofQBasic() = OtherList[i]
```

A boy can dream.

Comment: See also http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/05/why-you-dont-want-to-dynamically-create.html for why this is a stupid idea in the first place and how to accomplish what you *should* be trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2):

That would be done by (note that this is considered very bad practice, I wouldn't recommend it):

```
locals().update(dict(zip(MyList, OtherList)))
```

That would be for the current scope, use `globals()` for global assignments.

Comment: To the person who undid their up-vote, I've fixed it now. :)

Comment: it's worth noting that this is only making variables "for other variables" when you are pointing to a mutable object. for numbers and stings you will actually get a copy of the value... in otherwords, manipulating `word` may not manipulate `OtherList[MyList.index('word')]`

Comment: @underrun I was wondering about that... but I don't think there is a perfect way to do it. Quite rightly, too- I am ashamed of posting such blasphemous code. :D

Comment: granted. this is the answer to his question though ... its just there is not any "good" answer. you could also go with `eval` but that's also :'(

Comment: my intention with the question was to resolve an issue when you have a class that functions for another class's variable's datatype and you want to access the data in a particular way.

Comment: @MattMcCarthy OK- great, but that wasn't in your question. My answer resolves the issue illustrated in your post.

Comment: I, ugh, didn't say you didn't assist in resolving it.

Comment: @MattMcCarthy Good, I'm glad I could help. Also, I apoligise for any offense caused. If now you would like to apply the solution to something specific, try it first and then you could always ask a new question outlining what is not working as you want it to. Users will gladly help you then. If however my answer has been of assistance to the immediate problem, I would appreciate for you to [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: @AlexThornton, I did accept it good sir.  My secondary comment was just an addendum to the nature of my original question. Though a convention on the page linked by someone else did show me a method (in the non-pythonian usage) which I had simply overlooked. i.e. x = y = z = 0  I simply never thought to apply this style in a function/class before. In fact, I assumed it would be considered tacky :p

Comment: @MattMcCarthy You may have upvoted, but you did not accept yet. To accept, you need to click on the hollow tick below the vote counts so that it turns green.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't want to put it in a variable in scope but you could make it an attribute of an object:

```
class namespace(object): pass
ns = namespace()
ns.__dict__.update(dict(zip(MyList, OtherList)))
ns.word == OtherList[0] # True
```

or possibly if you want to use a for loop

```
class namespace(object): pass
ns = namespace()
for k, v in zip(MyList, OtherList):
    ns.__dict__[k] = v

ns.word == OtherList[0] # True
```